# Integrate the Miniprofiler to Console WCF Self Host

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

How to integrate the Miniprofiler to Console Self Host application which hosts the WCF Services.
How to get to know the DB hits that was carried out 
and queries getting executed via selfhost using the Miniprofiler ?

Host DB Layer is Entity Framework accessed via WCF.

Answer (score 0):

In the *general case* (not WCF self-host specifically), the key to this is providing a profiler-provider, via `MiniProfiler.Settings.ProfilerProvider`. This is the thing that must be able to resolve the profiler from the ambient state. By default, it selects `WebRequestProfilerProvider` - but that clearly doesn't apply. The easiest way to do this is to subclass `BaseProfilerProvider`, which only has a couple of methods to implement - and you can look at `WebProfilerProvider` to see examples, in particular of what happens in `Stop` for the non-trivial case where the results are not discarded. Presumably your WCF-oriented code would use `OperationContext.Current` for the ambient state.

The next question, though, is: what are you going to do with the results? Log them to the console? Append them in the WCF message? Most things will be possible, but will need to be implemented differently. The system itself only provides a web-based UI, but you can expand through the timings data to do whatever you need.

You might also want to see:

- http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.WCF/
- https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling.Wcf/WcfRequestProfilerProvider.cs
- https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Sample.Wcf